# Updating ElasticSearch mappings field type with existing data

Tags: amazon-web-services, elasticsearch, kibana, elastic-stack

I'm storing a few fields and for the sake of simplicity lets call the field in question 'age'. Initially ES created the index for me and it ended up choosing the wrong field type for 'age'. It's a string type right now instead of a numeric type. I'm aware that, I should have defined the mappings myself to begin with and force the data values been sent to be consistently all strings or numeric values.

What I've right now is an index with a ton of data that uses a 'string' type for age with following values: 1, 10, 'na', etc..

Now my question is: if I were to change the mapping from string to integer, would  indexing have any issues with the existing data values such as 'na' when being updated ??

I just wanted to ask first before I start creating a playground environment to test with a sample data set.

Comment: Did you create a mapping first?

Comment: no i have not created a mapping to begin with.

Answer (score 0):

What you can update according to the [doc](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/indices-put-mapping.html#updating-field-mappings):

> - new properties can be added to Object datatype fields.
> - new multi-fields can be added to existing fields.
> - doc_values can be disabled, but not enabled.
> - the ignore_above parameter can be updated.

Otherwise I am afraid you will have to create a new mapping and reindex your data, see this [post](https://gist.github.com/nicolashery/6317643) for example

Comment: I dont mind re-indexing but worried about mixed data values. Moving forward i want the age field to be a numeric field but not sure about what to do about existing mix of string and numeric data.

Comment: That's why you should define a mapping for your data (I know it can take some time) rather than defer it to elasticsearch

Comment: Definitely no doubt. But what options do you think I have moving forward?

Comment: What I would do is create a new index, create the correct mapping, and then use the Reindex API, also bear in mind to carefully read the documentation on mappings, as it can be quite painful to reindex once your database becomes huge, see the reindex api doc: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/docs-reindex.html